# Linking all Boost libraries in QT 5.12 Mingw

Tags: c++, qt, boost

Iam learning boost and test some examples, so I link boost libraries in my QT project with MinGW compiler, and I want to link all the libraries so i can use anything from filesystem to asio and go with different examples that use many classes.
this my .pro file which I link the boost libraries

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_1_66_0

LIBS += -LC:/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib     -llibboost_atomic-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_atomic-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_chrono-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_chrono-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_container-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_container-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_context-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_context-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_coroutine-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_coroutine-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_date_time-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_date_time-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_exception-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_exception-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_filesystem-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_filesystem-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_graph-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_graph-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_iostreams-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_iostreams-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_locale-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_locale-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_log-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_log-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_log_setup-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_log_setup-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_c99-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_c99-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_c99f-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_c99f-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_c99l-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_c99l-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_tr1-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_tr1-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_tr1f-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_tr1f-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_tr1l-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_math_tr1l-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_program_options-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_program_options-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_random-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_random-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_regex-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_regex-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_serialization-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_serialization-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_signals-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_signals-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_stacktrace_basic-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_stacktrace_basic-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_stacktrace_noop-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_stacktrace_noop-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_system-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_system-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_test_exec_monitor-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_test_exec_monitor-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_thread-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_thread-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_timer-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_timer-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_type_erasure-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_type_erasure-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_unit_test_framework-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_unit_test_framework-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_wave-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_wave-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_wserialization-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_66\
        -llibboost_wserialization-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
```

I go to the boost lib folder and add all the libraries as above, I start now testing some functions and I still got undefine refernce to some functions although I linked all the libararies and I use it in Release mode here is my main in which i use boost archive

```
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <cstring>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
using namespace boost::archive;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    ofstream out("D:/a.txt");
    text_oarchive oa(out);

    int a = INT_MAX;
    oa << a;
    out.close();


    return 0;
}
```

this is the error I got

```
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf1): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::_exception_code, char const*, char const*)'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEE5vsaveENS0_14object_id_typeE[__ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEE5vsaveENS0_14object_id_typeE]+0x69): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::_exception_code, char const*, char const*)'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEE5vsaveENS0_21object_reference_typeE[__ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEE5vsaveENS0_21object_reference_typeE]+0x62): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::_exception_code, char const*, char const*)'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEE5vsaveENS0_13class_id_typeE[__ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEE5vsaveENS0_13class_id_typeE]+0x63): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::_exception_code, char const*, char const*)'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEE5vsaveENS0_23class_id_reference_typeE[__ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEE5vsaveENS0_23class_id_reference_typeE]+0x63): undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::_exception_code, char const*, char const*)'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEE5vsaveENS0_13tracking_typeE[__ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_oarchiveINS0_13text_oarchiveEE5vsaveENS0_13tracking_typeE]+0x63): more undefined references to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::_exception_code, char const*, char const*)' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Release:63: release/Normal2.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:36: release] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/WorkPlace/CppProject/cpp/build-Normal2-Desktop_QT_5_12_0_MinGW_32_bit-Release'
17:41:30: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\Tools\mingw730_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Normal2 (kit: Desktop QT 5.12.0 MinGW 32-bit)
When executing step "Make"
17:41:30: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

so what mistake i made to give me those erros, and I already linked all the libraries and add them to my Project i did not test more examples yet so i don't know if I will got some errors more if i used different classes.
Iam using this website to learn more about boost library [here](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/) so I am going with different examples to test and I need to link all boost libraries
**Update**
This now my .pro file i removed the lib at the beggining and I remove debug libraries and use only release here is my .pro file

```
LIBS += -LC:/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib     -lboost_atomic-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_chrono-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_container-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_context-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_coroutine-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_date_time-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_exception-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_filesystem-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_graph-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_iostreams-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_locale-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_log-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_log_setup-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_math_c99-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_math_c99f-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_math_c99l-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_math_tr1-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_math_tr1f-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_math_tr1l-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_program_options-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_random-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_regex-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_serialization-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_signals-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_stacktrace_basic-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_stacktrace_noop-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_system-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_test_exec_monitor-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_thread-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_timer-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_type_erasure-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_unit_test_framework-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_wave-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
        -lboost_wserialization-mgw63-mt-x32-1_66\
```

but still the same problem, if the order matter what order i need to make this example work?, also if there is a way to add them all at once with a right order it will be better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the lib part from -llibboost...., so, it should be: -lboost.... Anyway, Why do not link only what you really want?

Comment: On top of the above comment you also seem to be trying to link debug and release libraries at the same time. And I agree with @Amadeus you should link only the libraries you are using.

Comment: Also remember that link *order* matters. For many linkers, objects *requiring* a symbol must be listed before objects *implementing* the symbol on the linker command line.

Comment: I want to link them all because I really don't know exactly the order i should link them and which libraries to add to make what i need work, so I think the easy way is to link them all what you think?

Comment: "what you think?" - *I* think it's a really lousy idea. *I* think you should learn more about your tool chain and the libraries you use. Then link only what you need in the correct order. You'll save build time, application size, debugging headaches (like *why* is this library initialization code called? I don't even use that), application startup time (linked library symbols need to be resolved at app startup - this is not free), etc. Spend the time to learn to do it properly, then do so. If you don't know what you are doing, don't employ a hack to work around it; learn, then do correctly.

Comment: It looks like you have a broken boost installation. This program only needs `boost_serialization`. All other libraries you are linking is are harmless noise.